# java, unable to understand the concept of back-referencing within the context of nested capturing group

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of capturing group. I read on Java tutorial oracle:

> For nested capturing groups, backreferencing works in exactly the same
>   way: Specify a backslash followed by the number of the group to be
>   recalled.

Because of my inexperience, I have not been able to understand it conceptually and the tutorial did not provide any code example. Could someone please explain this concept to me, preferably with some code? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think they are talking about this

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      nested
      (                             # (2 start)
           groups  
      )                             # (2 end)
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s     
 (                             # (3 start)
      \1 
      \s 
      \2+ 
 )                             # (3 end)
```

You can see that group 1 *also* contains group 2.

You can then reference what matched in group 1 with a backreference
that will also contain what matched in group 2.

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 38 ) 
nestedgroups nestedgroups groupsgroups  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 12 ) 
nestedgroups  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 6 , len 6 ) 
groups  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 13 , len 25 ) 
nestedgroups groupsgroups
```